# Can someone help me in writing a function to plot circles in ESRI javascript api ver 4.5?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am new to programming and wondering if someone can help me in writing a simple global function to plot a circle based on radius and a center point (lat,long). Basically, i need function that  uses variables such as x,y,r to plot a circle using ESRI javscript api 4.x.

```
 <script src = 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.5/init.js'></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href 
    "https://js.arcgis.com/4.5/esri/css/main.css">
```

I tried many things including the tutorial samples available on ESRI website but nothing worked for me.

```
    <script>
    let mapview;
    let map;
    let layer;
    let r;
    let Request;
    let selectedService;
    let Graphic;
    let Circle
    const DEFAULT_BASEMAP = "streets"
    const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 100;
    //second commit
    require (["esri/Map",
         "esri/views/MapView",
         "esri/request",
         "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
         "esri/widgets/Legend",
         "esri/widgets/Search",
         "esri/Graphic",
         "esri/geometry/Geometry",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/geometry/Circle"], 
        function(Map, 
            MapView, 
            CircleClass,
            esriRequest, 
            MapLayer, 
            Legend,
            Search,
            GraphicClass, Geometry, Polygon)
        {   
             Request= esriRequest;
             Graphic = GraphicClass;
            Circle=CircleClass;
             map = new Map({basemap:DEFAULT_BASEMAP})
             let viewoptions = {container: "upright", map: map, 
             center: [-122.388, 37.768], scale: 10000}
             mapview = new MapView(viewoptions);

         });

    function drawPoint (x,y) {

   let p = {
    type: "point",
    longitude: x,
    latitude: y
   }
   let s = {
    type: "picture-marker",
    url:"CMS.png",
    width: "40px",
    height: "80px"

   }
   let graphic = new Graphic({geometry: p, symbol: s})
   mapview.graphics.add(graphic);
   }

function drawEvent (x,y) {

let p = {
    type: "point",
    longitude: x,
    latitude: y
}
let s = {
    type: "simple-marker",
    color: getRandomColor(),
    size: 60

    }

let graphic = new Graphic({geometry: p, symbol: s})
mapview.graphics.add(graphic);


}


/* Here is the function i want to create so i can call elsewhere*/
function drawCircle (x,y,r) {


}



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Circle" object can be created by taking the center point and radius information in the constructor method.
Example app:
https://codepen.io/mcantonbul/pen/pozPQqe

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/geometry/Circle",
  "esri/geometry/Point",
  "esri/Graphic"
], function(Map, MapView, Circle, Point, Graphic) {
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 4,
    center: [15, 65] // longitude, latitude
  });

  view.on("click", function(event) {
    drawCircle(event.mapPoint.x, event.mapPoint.y, 200000);
  });
  var fillSymbol = {
    type: "simple-fill", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
    color: [227, 139, 79, 0.8],
    outline: {
      // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
      color: [255, 255, 255],
      width: 1
    }
  };

  function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
    var centerPoint = new Point({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      spatialReference: view.spatialReference
    });

    var myCircle = new Circle({
      center: centerPoint,
      radius: r
    });
    var circleGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: myCircle,
      symbol: fillSymbol
    });
    console.log(myCircle);
    // Add the graphics to the view's graphics layer
    view.graphics.add(circleGraphic);
  }
```